# ic_launcher image not showing

Tags: android, xml

I created an Empty Activity on Android Studio 3.3.

I have problem with the ic_launcher. I have searched all related questions and answers before posting this question. I followed the link what uses Android Launcher Icon Generator, copy and paste, over writting the folder as well as trying to re-created the project as new and doing all over again.

Somehow the icons still uses the default android icon and doesn't extract my custom icons.

Only the icon and roundIcon doesn't work. The logo works fine at the action bar.

I also right click on the res folder and select New --> New Image Asset. The Legacy folder also shows the default icon and when I select Next, it will auto over-right my custom icons.

I noticed however, when I import an existing code project, the icons remain as their own. And I tried copying over to my project, but the icon still doesn't work and defaults back to the android icon.

```
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: have you over-witten all the "*.png" icons under `/mipmap`? You also have to overwrite `ic_launcher_foreground` and `ic_launcher_background` under `drawable` folder.

Comment: yes, I over written all png. in mipmap and also included drawable folder (e.g. drawable-hdpi ..etc). Do i need to include ic_launcher.xml in drawable folder as well? I know there is an existing ic_launcher_foreground and background already exist there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding your icon files as new files in the drawable instead of overwriting the ic_launcher, and then just changing the android manifast to use   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_my_icon_launcher" instead? Maybe it doesn't overwrite the default correctly.

Comment: meaning, delete and copy over? Yes, did that as well. I also deleted the xml files and re-type it again rather than copy paste. Could it be my android studio is corrupted? But then again, when i import code from github, the app debug and run smoothly with my new custom icons when I just copy paste in the folders. So I don't understand why new project doesn't work. I might have to try existing working projects, clear the folders and put in the codes? But that's gonna be lots of errors for sure!

Comment: I was thinking more adding new icons instead of overwriting the ic_launcher that is there by default in android studio. I don't know if this would work, but you could try to call your own icon ic_my_icon and then change the lines in the XML file to get that file instead of the ic_launcher. Does this make sense?

Comment: YES! It works completely.. Thank you so much. I'm so happy. Was searching high and low all over the internet. Dare not post the question here incase it was a repeat. But it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it happen that something is left over between installs of the same app, with the effect of the Android default app is displayed, instead of the launcher app.  The following procedure resolved my issue

1. from Settings, force quit the app
2. clear all app storage and cache
3. uninstall app
4. re-install app

Answer (score -2):

Copy your code and paste it into a new project ..... Based on experience